# Как отправить анимированный стикер в бот?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Есть анонимный чат бот ,я написал функцию ,которая позволяет отправлять эмодзи в бот,выглядит она вот так

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types='stickers')
def bot_stickers(message):
if message.chat.type == 'private':
    chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
    if chat_info != False:
        bot.send_sticker(chat_info[1], message.sticker.file_id)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Вы не начали диалог!')
```

Но я не могу написать функцию,которая позволяет отправлять анимированные стикеры

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно убрать s

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types='sticker')
def bot_sticker(message):
try:
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
        if chat_info != False:
            bot.send_sticker(chat_info[1], message.sticker.file_id)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Вы не начали диалог!')            

except:
    pass
```